# Jenkins with SVN publisher finishes success but doesn't post

Tags: svn, jenkins

So in my Jenkins project I have SVN publisher plugin and turned on for a job.  The job is supposed to run a cucumber script, and in the script it modifies files.  I'm using svn publisher to publish the changed files to SVN so when we come in the next day, we can update the project and get the new numbers for the day.

I get `Attempting to import to SVN` message, as well as the `SVN Publisher` line and `Finished: SUCCESS` message, however when I look at SVN the project files are left unchanged.  I have verified the target path and the svn path as being valid, and hudson seems to think that it is publishing correctly but I don't see it in SVN.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a post-build action to trigger a second job (build other projects -> projects to build, tick 'trigger only if build succeeds'). All this second job does is run a command (using the 'execute shell' field) and after run script(for publish your changes in workdirectory) you will see new commit.
Enjoy!!!